# How to get key type from pythons TypedDict

Tags: python

if I have a TypedDict like:

```py
class Td(TypedDict):
    bar: str
    foo: str
```

and want to have a function thats parameter needs to be a key of that TypedDict, like:

```py
def hello_Td(key: str, td: Td):
    return 'Hello ' + td[key]
```

With above code, I get a warning saying that key is str, expected Literal['bar', 'foo'].

Is there someway to automatically generate that literal-union type?

Something like:

```py
td_keys = Literal(Td.keys())
def hello_Td(key: td_keys, td: Td):
    return 'Hello ' + td[key]
```

## Update 1

RepEx: https://pastebin.com/vaVpJCBv
[image]

Comment: Your example works for me in python3.8. It outputs Hello Bar, Hello Foo

Comment: @forgetso the code itself runns, it's the typechecking I want to get right. The function with the manul_literal is more strict, and gives no warning, but I looking for a way to automateit so I don't have to repeate myself.

Comment: Ha, yeah I noticed that after I re-read your Q. Pycharm uses mypy (https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/python-3-5-type-hinting-in-pycharm-5/) and this is possibly a bug in mypy: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7178

Comment: May be a bit related, but I want my function to be strictly typed, so I want the parameter type to be a union of the key literals, just feels like there should be a way to generate it from the TypedDict, insted of adding all keys manual to a literal.

Comment: Nice solution until you don't have 50 keys. It's not so nice to keep synchronized keys typed twice (`TypedDict` and `Literal`). Worse, I don't see another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your first order of business should be to create a new data-type to represent the allowable dictionary keys.

Let us suppose that the new data-type is named `Country`

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class Country(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name
    RUSSIA        = auto()
    CHINA         = auto()
    UNITED_STATES = auto()
    AUSTRALIA     = auto()
    BRAZIL        = auto()
```

Let us inspect some examples:

```py
example1 = Country("UNITED_STATES")
example2 = Country("RUSSIA")

print("str(example1)".ljust(20), " == ", str(example1))
print("repr(example1)".ljust(20), " == ", repr(example1))
print("example2".ljust(20), " == ", example2)
print("example1.value".ljust(20), " == ", example1.value)
print("example1.name".ljust(20),  " == ", example1.name)
```

The output printed to the console is as follows:

```
str(example1)         ==  Country.UNITED_STATES
repr(example1)        ==  <Country.UNITED_STATES: 'UNITED_STATES'>
example2              ==  Country.RUSSIA
example1.value        ==  UNITED_STATES
example1.name         ==  UNITED_STATES
```

Normally, enumerated data-types are whole numbers.
For example `RUSSIA == 41`.
However, it is more self-documenting to use strings.

Feel free to use something other than a enumerated data type (`enum`). The goal is simply to create a class to represent allowable dictionary keys.

Below is an implementation which is **not** an enumerated data-type:

```
import string

class Kountry:
    BRAZIL        = "BRAZIL"
    CHINA         = "CHINA"
    UNITED_STATES = "UNITED_STATES"

    def __init__(this, dirty_stryng:str):
        stryng = "".join(str(ch) for ch in dirty_stryng)
        stryng = stryng.upper()
        is_letter = lambda ch: ch in string.ascii_uppercase
        stryng = "".join(filter(is_letter, stryng))
        if not stryng in type(this).COUNTRIES:
            # print invalid input
            # maximum 30 characters. do not print 9,000 characters
            # remove line-breaks, carriage returns etc...
            # string representation of invalid input must fit all on one line
            msg = repr(str(dirty_stryng))[:30]
            raise ValueError(msg)
        this._string = stryng

    def __getattr__(this, attrname:str):
        if has_attr(this._string, attrname):
            return getattr(this._string, attrname)
        return getattr(type(this), attrname)

    def __str__(this):
        return this._string
```

We can take this non-`enum` out for a spin:

```py
brazil = Kountry("brazil")
r = str(brazil)
print("str(brazil)".ljust(20), " is ", r)
r = brazil.split()
print("brazil.split()".ljust(20), " is ", r)
r = brazil.join("$-@")
print("brazil.join(\"$-@\")".ljust(20), " is ", r)
```

The console output is:

```
str(brazil)           is  BRAZIL
brazil.split()        is  ['BRAZIL']
brazil.join("$-@")    is  $BRAZIL-BRAZIL@
```

After defining a new data-type named "`Country`", you then want to do the following:

1. Define functions whose input parameters must be instances of the `Country` class.
2. Create a dictionary whose keys must be instances of the `Country` class.

---

We can create a function whose parameters are supposed to be instances of the Country class as follows:

```py
def to_pretty_string(cntry:Country):
    country_str = str(cntry.name)
    out_str = "-xXx-".join(["", country_str, ""])
    return out_str
```

Where I wrote `:Country` on the input parameter... that is a python "*type hint*". The *type-hint* says that the function argument should be an instance of the `Country` class.

In case you are curious, we have the following output to the console when we call (use) the `to_pretty_string` function:

```py
print(to_pretty_string(Country.BRAZIL))
print(to_pretty_string(Country.UNITED_STATES))
print(to_pretty_string(Country.RUSSIA))

# -xXx-BRAZIL-xXx-
# -xXx-UNITED_STATES-xXx-
# -xXx-RUSSIA-xXx-
```

In a language like **C++**, we would use a "*template class*" for the dictionary. In **Java**, they are called "generics" instead of "templates". However, it is the same concept whether it be called a "template class" or a "generic class"

I wish that the following was real code:

```py
# WARNING: this is not real python

# Create a dictionary whose keys are Countries
head_counts = Dict[Country]

# Populate the dictionary
head_counts[Country.UNITED_STATES] = 329.5*1000000
head_counts[Country.RUSSIA]        = 144.1*1000000
head_counts[Country.BRAZIL]        = 212.6*1000000

# End of wishful thinking
```

However, the python programming language does not have much in the way of generic classes in its standard libraries. You might have to write your own class in order to have a dictionary with string-only keys (`Dict[str]`) or a dictionary whose keys are decimal numbers only (`Dict[float]`)

What we can do is create a *type-hint*.

However, the *type-hint* does not create a real dictionary; only a special object used in parameter lists to specify that the object should probably be a dictionary whose keys are Countries:

```py
import typing as typ
import Country 

def funky_the_function(dee:typ.Dict[Country, object]):
    print("Keys to `dee` should be instances of `Country`")
    dee[Country.UNITED_STATES] = 329.5*1000000
    dee[Country.RUSSIA]        = 144.1*1000000
    dee[Country.BRAZIL]        = 212.6*1000000
    dee[342] # Danger Will Robinson! Danger!
    return
```