# Python: Annotate variable as key of a TypedDict

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Basically a distilled down version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628872/how-to-get-key-type-from-pythons-typeddict) (as yet unanswered) question.

I want to state that a variable should only take on values that are keys in a `TypedDict`.

At present I'm defining a separate `Literal` type to represent the keys, for example:

```py
from typing import Literal, TypedDict


class MyTD(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int


mytd = MyTD(a=1, b=2)

key = "a"

mytd[key]  # error: TypedDict key must be a string literal; expected one of ('a', 'b')

MyTDKeyT = Literal["a", "b"]

typed_key: MyTDKeyT = "b"

mytd[typed_key]  # no error
```

I would like to be able to replace the `Literal` definition for all the usual reasons of wanting to minimize duplicated code.

Pseudo-code:

```py
key: Keys[MyTD] = "a"
mytd[key]  # would be no error
not_key: Keys[MyTD] = "z"  # error
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

To clarify, given that mypy can tell me that the key type needs to be a literal of "a" or "b", I'm hoping there might be a less error prone way to annotate a variable to that type, rather than having to maintain two separate lists of keys side-by-side, once in the `TypedDict` definition, once in the `Literal` definition.

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7178 seems like a known issue

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't think that's the OP's issue. They want to be able to replace the literal type definition with something from the `TypedDict` type... `key = 'a'` has to infer `str`, which mypy correctly identifies as wrong. That was [fixed here](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/7645), indeed, we can see the fixed behavior above

Comment: @IainShelvington That issue seems to be about having mypy recognize that a string literal stored to a variable should be allowed as a key to retrieve a value. It evolves to suggesting the exact use-case that I currently use (defining the distinct `Literal` or `Final` type).

Comment: I have same issue. I would like to define a function which takes some TypedDict and a valid key of it, but figured out there is now way to do it. Something like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

Comment: This is a valid code in [**pyright**](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright). Probably the best way to handle this case in type checking via **mypy** is to either cast it to a `Literal`, or use a `# type: ignore` comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MyPy, I don't think this is possible.  I ran this experiment:

```
from typing import TypedDict

class MyTD(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: int

d = MyTD(a='x', b=2)
reveal_type(list(d))
```

The MyPy output was:

```
Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.str]"
```

This indicates that internally it is not tracking the keys as literals.  Otherwise, we would expect:

```
Revealed type is "builtins.list[Literal['A', 'B']]"
```

Also, this errors out in MyPy, so `__required_keys__` isn't even inspectable:

```
reveal_type(MyTD.__required_keys__)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this your time, Raymond - that makes sense. It feels like a missed opportunity - but you could write a whole static type system with what I don't know. Given that it isn't rejected as an idea in PEP 589, I'll live in hope.