# Typing Key, Value of a TypedDict without additional class in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-typing

I would like to use the Typing module in Python 3.8.
Python 3.8 features a TypedDict in the Typing module.
I have a function with arguments like this:
from Typing import

```
def groupDataFrame(df: pd.DataFrame, somelist: List[str], somedict: TypedDict[str: Callable]:
    pass
```

But it doesn't allow me to specify the dictionary like this, throwing a TypeError:
`TypeError: '_TypedDictMeta' object is not subscriptable`

There is a solution that utilizes an additional class, but is quite an ugly solution:

[How to get key type from pythons TypedDict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628872/how-to-get-key-type-from-pythons-typeddict)

Any idea how to do it without an additional class?

Comment: Right, because that isn't how it is meant to be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't subscript TypedDict; you're meant to instantiate or subclass one [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict):

```
Point2D = TypedDict('Point2D', x=int, y=int, label=str)
Point2D = TypedDict('Point2D', {'x': int, 'y': int, 'label': str})
```

With that in mind, you can just inline that in your signature:

```
def x(a: TypedDict('A', x=int)):
  pass
```

Comment: The last example of inlining the TypedDict - with pyright atleast seems to give: `Call expression not allowed in type expression` and doesn't really use the type  - https://pyright-play.net/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYA7A5nAhgZwQKHwA0AVZAUzgF4EA6MscgEwBFgBjGACgHJSKeAGjgAPKgDMANhCwwAlPiblx2Jky4iAXHH6NhibVJnzN%2BOObhRyMAK5RUogNo8RPALpwA1HESElKrDUAJg1tGHoKVg5uPgZyIVEJaVk5fUNkkzMLK1t7Jxd3Lx9CQPUAbwAiEQrtAEYAX2Eg2gAGBSA